# What are the basic concepts in command line arguments syntax

Tags: command-line-arguments

I want to implement a script which gets some command line arguments and options.
There are so many different syntax types in command line arguments that I'm sometime confused.

Here are some examples:

```
./my_script -f -abc --file --name=lior -Dsomething=value -arg val
```

... and I guess there are even more...

Can anyone please make some order here?

(Best practices and recommendations are welcomed too)

Thanks,

Lior

Comment: this may be best asked at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are conventions, but no hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some discussion and interesting links in [this post](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/command-line-syntax-some-basic-concepts/). Also refer to [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch10s05.html) and [that document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/standard-options.html).